# How to enable PL/R for regular users in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I am learning/testing PL/R for PostgreSQL (9.5), and tried to verify the installation with `SELECT * FROM  plr_environ();`. But this works only for the superuser for pg, and not for my regular pg user.

What I did was:

1.I did `CREATE EXTENSION plr;` as `postgres` into a template database, and then created database for my user name with `createdb -T my_template my_user`.

2.If use `psql -U postgres` on the template db, I can get:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM  plr_environ();
        name        |            value             
--------------------+------------------------------
 PG_OOM_ADJUST_FILE | /proc/self/oom_score_adj
 PG_GRANDPARENT_PID | 499
 PGLOCALEDIR        | /usr/share/locale
 PGSYSCONFDIR       | /etc/postgresql-common
 LANG               | en_US.UTF-8
 PWD                | /var/lib/postgresql
 PGDATA             | /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main
 LC_COLLATE         | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_CTYPE           | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MESSAGES        | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MONETARY        | C
 LC_NUMERIC         | C
 LC_TIME            | C
```

However, if I do this on the new db created from the template, I got the error:

```
=> SELECT * FROM  plr_environ();
ERROR:  permission denied for function plr_environ
```

Can someone help explain how I can fix the workflow to make `PL/R` work for regular users?

Comment: I imagine, in this case, you are the superuser and you're doing setups for other users, so I would look at the permissions in PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main which will likely say postgres:postgres, and then you're likely going to ask yourself if you want your other users in postgres's zone or should you modify the template PGDATA to each users' own file location with permissions set to user:user. So not a PL/R problem per se.

Comment: @chris I am only the database su. I have used the same work flow for other extensions such as postgis without a problem. I don't know what is different here about plr.

Comment: Everything is okay until you try to do something. Select is certainly doing something like changing the underlying file. Whereas extension creation just speaks to the capabilities of what might be achieved within a given database. But anyway are you saying that PGDATA path leads to a file where everyone can do anything. Permission denied generally suggests this isn't the case and either postgres or root aren't having any of it. What's you're ls -la on the users' template?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can find is from [this blog](http://hcisql.blogspot.com/2012/05/to-execute-plr-functions-is-mandatory.html). It seems that **only superusers** can execute PL/R functions. Quoting the blog:

> To execute plr functions is mandatory that the user be a superuser,
>   because this language is considered unreliable at this moment. ...
>
> The solution is alter user rights to this condition.

So, it seems that currently it's not possible for non-superusers to use PL/R functions.